# SSIS Split Condition

Tags: sql, ssis

I need to implement `SCD` Type 2
this is my condition in my split condition before updating my `RecordEndDate` and eventually adding it in the database. But even though it does not satisfy the condition it still keeps on adding it in the database

```
((PlateNo == Stage_PlateNo)) && (([Car Name] != [Stage_Model]) || 
 ([Manufacturer] != [Stage_Manufacturer]) ||
  [Year Model] != Stage_Year || 
  [Car Body Type] != Stage_BodyType ||
  Transmission != Stage_Transmission ||
 [Daily Rate (in Peso)] != Stage_DailyRate
 )
```

Comment: Check whether you are connecting the correct data flow path of split transformation to your OLEDB commmand for updating the date .you shouldn't be selecting the default output name

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of this part of the package? Maybe add some more info to the question too.

Comment: If you don't actually see SSIS reporting rows being sent through the other conditional output, like praveen suggested, then there wouldn't be much more we can tell you from this post =\

Answer (score 1):

IMO your requirements are far too complex to attempt in an SSIS Expression.  I recommend you recode this logic in a Script transformation.  I would pre-create a new Column e.g. Include_Row and in the Script set it's value to yes or no.

This approach will give you much more code flexibility and better debugging possibilities.